# Asp.net buttonclick server event firing when textbox is entered

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox and a button.

The button has a `btn_click(obj, eventargs)` on codebehind.

This is on `master` page.

What I want is when the textbox is focused and click `enter`,

I want to run that function, in other words, click the button.

So, I wrote...

```
$("#" + "<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>").keypress(function (e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    $("#" + "<%= imgBtnSearch.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

On server side function, I am redirecting to another page.

Since it is not redirecting, can i assume that it is not working?

Is there anything I can make it work?

});

Comment: Try enclosing them in a panel and setup the `defaultbutton` (to your required button) property of the panel, this should trigger the button click

Comment: @V4Vendetta this is worthy of being an answer in it slef

Comment: @JonP Added it as an answer nonetheless he has accepted the JQuery way :)

Comment: @Vendetta, Sry man.. I know the defaultbutton way.. and it's not the way I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#" + "<%= txtSearch.ClientID%>").keypress(function (e) {
          var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
          if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#" + "<%= imgBtnSearch.ClientID%>").click();
        }});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
   <asp:Panel ID="Pnl1" runat="server" DefaultButton="BtnTest">
   <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="BtnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="BtnTest_Click" />
   </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Try this this will trigger the "BtnTest" only for the textbox "TxtTest"

Answer (score 0):

You should try enclose the `Textbox` and the `Button` in a `Panel` and set the DefaultButton property for the panel as the button. This will ensure that when you press enter in the textbox the button click would be triggered

Or you can do it in another fashion by setting the DefaultButton for the form like
`Page.Form.DefaultButton = [yourbutton]`

Answer (score 0):

william!

Please provide a server side function code, may be problem is there. If it's ok with server-side handler, then you should open JavaScript console and check if there's any errors (If so, then redirect won't occur).

AND try this function instead of yours to cause a button server click.

```
$("#" + "<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>").keypress(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        <%= scriptPostBackButton1 %>
    }
}
```

In this example, hitting 'enter' down on textbox causes server-side click handler with postback. Is this a behavior you need?

Code-behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string scriptPostBackButton1 = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            scriptPostBackButton1 = 
                ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(clickableButton, "", "", false, false, true, true, true, ""));
        }
    }


    protected void clickableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = "ok, it's working";            
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbEnter" runat="server" onkeydown=" return clientHandler(event);"  />
    <asp:Button ID="clickableButton" runat="server" Text="click" Width="49px"  />
</form>
```